# Two inline Condition Check

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to avoid extra lines of code. so i am running this by you guys to see if it correct. i wrote an inline condition to check for 2 elments in an object.

if the Notification Date (EndsAt) is assigned and the errormessage is NullorEmpty  or  the Notification Date is not assigned  and the errormessage is not NullorEmpty then return "09".

```
        if ((Notification.EndsAt.HasValue && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Notification.ErrorMessage)) || (!Notification.EndsAt.HasValue && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Notification.ErrorMessage)))
        {
            return "09";
        }
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: whats your question??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a Code Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is your question?

**Are my conditions correct in checking 2 elements?**

If you're asking if your conditions are correct and do what you ask them to do, then that looks OK. The parentheses and bangs go where they should.

**Is there any way I can reduce the condition checks?**

Can't answer that since you didn't mention what you want to return for cases where:

---

EndsAt is not Assigned & ErrorMessage IS NullorEmpty

EndsAt is assigned & ErrorMessage IS NOT NullorEmpty

---

**Can I improve performance and readability?**

Since the conditional logic here depends on whether EndsAt hasValue and if ErrorMessage is null or empty, you could just store them in variables and compare those variables with the boolean logic you supplied. This reduces length of code (and improves readability), and if getting those boolean values multiple times in your program takes awhile, having them as local variables will improve performance. (think about how saving the count of elements in an array and using it multiple times (while it remains unchanged) is more efficient than calling the count method multiple times when you know the count won't change.

Comment: Thank you very much. my question was **Are my conditions correct in checking 2 elements** ?  @matrixanomaly

Comment: for these cases (1.)EndsAt is not Assigned & ErrorMessage IS NullorEmpty

and (2.) EndsAt is assigned & ErrorMessage IS NOT NullorEmpty i am not intrested in them